# Youtube API upload video size and length limit

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a limit on video file size and length when I use YouTube API to upload videos to YouTube?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update :** From [Google support link](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/71673?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

*By default, you can upload videos that are up to 15 minutes long. To upload longer videos, follow the steps below to verify your account. If you have live streaming access, long uploads are enabled by default.*

**To upload longer videos, verify your account with the following steps:**

1. On a computer, go to the upload page at youtube.com/upload.
2. At the bottom of the page, click Increase your limit. You can also go directly to https://www.youtube.com/verify.
3. Follow the steps to verify your account. You can choose to receive a verification code through a text message on a mobile phone or an automated voice call.
4. Once you've verified your account, you can upload videos that are longer than 15 minutes.

Make sure you're using an up-to-date version of your browser to upload files greater than 20GB.

**Maximum upload size:**

The maximum file size you can upload is 128GB or 12 hours, whichever is less. We've changed the limits on uploads in the past, so you may see older videos that are longer than 12 hours.

**Initial Answer(Outdated) :**

It's currently `2GB` for browser-based uploads and `1GBb` for direct uploads, at least until 
the server which handles direct uploads is updated to handle `2GB` as well.

Please check below links for more details :
i) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/JqAX4n3a4Fk
ii)http://smallbusiness.chron.com/there-size-limit-youtube-26654.html

Comment: This answer is outdated.

Answer (score 30):

The more up-to-date answer is here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/71673?hl=en

15 minutes is the default max length, but that can be extended by visiting https://www.youtube.com/verify  The webpage says to make sure you're using an 'up-to-date' version of your browser to upload files over 20GB.  The current (as of Nov 12, 2016) maximum file size is 128GB and the maximum duration is 12 hours.

Comment: That site now says _"The maximum file size you'll be able to upload to YouTube is **128GB** and the maximum duration is **11 hours.**"_

Comment: It became 12 hours again.

Answer (score 5):

You can now upload videos in excess of 15 minutes long.  All you need to do is verify your YouTube account using the following link.  Make sure you are logged into your YouTube account:

https://www.youtube.com/verify

Make sure you’re using an up-to-date version of your browser so you can upload files greater than 20GB. The maximum file size you'll be able to upload to YouTube is 128GB and the maximum duration is 11 hours.

Comment: @user1153551 not every answer that contains a link is a link-only answer. In this case, the link is part of the answer, instead of the place where the actual answer can be found. Please be a little more careful when reviewing ;)

Comment: I've increased my limit and I still can't upload 30 minute videos with the YT API.